# More efficient way to get a data matrix based on some value and index matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, variable-assignment

Assume I have a vector of values like:

```
M=3;val<-rnorm(M)
```

and the corresponding index matrix like:

```
N=20;J=10;ind<-matrix(sample(1:M,N*J,replace=T),nrow=J)
```

I can easily assign the values with their indices to get the data matrix as:

```
x<-matrix(val[ind],J,N)
```

Now I have a matrix of values like:

```
val<-matrix(rnorm(M*J),nrow=J)
```

and need to assign the values and indices row by row (i.e., one row in val with one row in ind) to get the data matrix.

I can do this with a for loop as:

```
x<-ind;
for(j in 1:J){x[j,]<-val[j,ind[j,]]}
```

But I wonder if there's more efficient way to do this, especially to avoid using the for loop?

I need to do resampling and repeat the assigning process hundreds of thousands of times. So I worry that the for loop will take up a lot of time.

Comment: I am slightly uncertain as to 'why' this is. Are you perhaps simply looking for `matrix(..., byrow = FALSE)`, which would fill in the matrix by column. This should let you fill in the matrix by column in the `matrix` call directly.

Comment: Sorry there are typos. But the issue is not on x, but to apply val and ind row by row, as shown in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another three methods, one using `sapply`, one *matrix subsetting* and one *vector subsetting*. Matrix and vector subsetting looks to be faster, the one with `sapply` slower, than the for loop.

Currently

```
matrix(val[1:J + (ind-1)*J],J,N)
```

looks like to be the fastest way.

```
M <- 3; N <- 20; J <- 10
ind <- matrix(sample(1:M,N*J,replace=T),nrow=J)
val <- matrix(rnorm(M*J),nrow=J)

x<-ind;
for(j in 1:J){x[j,]<-val[j,ind[j,]]}

identical(x, t(sapply(1:J, function(j) val[j,ind[j,]])))
#[1] TRUE

identical(x, matrix(val[matrix(c(rep(1:J, N), ind), ncol=2)],J,N))
#[1] TRUE
#Other ways for rep(1:J, N)
identical(x, matrix(val[matrix(c(row(ind), ind), ncol=2)],J,N))
#[1] TRUE
identical(x, matrix(val[matrix(c(slice.index(ind, 1), ind), ncol=2)],J,N))
#[1] TRUE

#Vector subsetting as suggested by Aaron
identical(x, matrix(val[row(ind) + (ind-1)*J],J,N))
#[1] TRUE
#Other ways
identical(x, matrix(val[1:J + (ind-1)*J],J,N))
#[1] TRUE
identical(x, matrix(val[sweep((ind-1)*J, 1, 1:J, "+")],J,N))
#[1] TRUE
```

Speed comparison:

```
library(microbenchmark)

f1 <- function() {
  x<-ind;
  for(j in 1:J){x[j,]<-val[j,ind[j,]]}
}
f2 <- function() {t(sapply(1:J, function(j) val[j,ind[j,]]))}
f3 <- function() {matrix(val[matrix(c(row(ind), ind), ncol=2)],J,N)}
f4 <- function() {matrix(val[row(ind) + (ind-1)*J],J,N)} #Comment from Aaron
f5 <- function() {matrix(val[1:J + (ind-1)*J],J,N)}

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), f5(), setup=gc)
#Unit: microseconds
# expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
# f1() 16.540 18.3595 20.11216 19.8820 20.7915  36.201   100
# f2() 43.514 46.3650 49.77573 48.0320 49.5120 113.631   100
# f3()  8.325  9.3265 10.38931  9.9425 10.4825  46.561   100
# f4()  6.934  7.8270  9.00286  8.4405  9.1355  25.840   100
# f5()  5.839  6.8730  7.71322  7.3520  8.3145  16.349   100
```

Comment: Nice. Out of curiosity I tried doing the matrix subsetting "manually" using `row(ind) + (ind-1)*J` instead of the matrix and it was just about the same speed, maybe a tiny increase.

Comment: Great! Thanks GKi & Aaron. I didn't even realize a matrix can be subsetted in so many ways.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a matrix can be subset or subset-assigned using a two-column matrix as row and column indices. So

```
i_idx = rep(1:J, each = ncol(ind))
x_idx = cbind(i_idx, 1:ncol(ind))
val_idx = cbind(i_idx, as.vector(t(ind[1:J,])))

x[x_idx] = val[val_idx]
```

Comment: This indeed avoids the for loop. But, to my surprise, it takes even longer time. I need to do resampling and repeat the assigning process hundreds of thousands of times. So I worry that the for loop will take up a lot of time. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Luwei, it's not the matrix subsetting that is slow here, it's just that the matrix wasn't formed as simply as possible. GKi shows how to speed that part up.